# Display API data on other react pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router-dom

I am currently training on React and am having a problem. As you can see on the screenshot, I would like to click on the product name to redirect to a description page of this product. I used react-router-dom for the illusion of multiple pages in the app but I can't seem to display the API data on another page.
I would like to be able to click on a product title to be able to access the details of this product.

You will find my code below

Thank you very much in advance for your explanations

[Image of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAd7x.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import './css/Products.css'
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
import Products from './Components/Products';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,} from 'react-router-dom';
import ProductsDetails from './Components/ProductsDetails';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App"> 
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Products} />
          <Route path="/products-details/:id" component={ProductsDetails} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/Products.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../Components/ProductsDetails'

export default class Products extends Component {
    state = {
        productsData: []
      }
      componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=7')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
          this.setState ({
            productsData: res.data
          })
        })
      }
    render() {
        const listsProducts = this.state.productsData.map(listProduct => {
            return <tbody className="products__body">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{listProduct.title}</td>
                        <td>{listProduct.category}</td>
                        <td>{listProduct.price}</td>
                        <td>{Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100}</td>
                    </tr> 
              </tbody>
          })
        return (
            <main className="products">
                <h1 className="products__title">Products management</h1>
                <table cellSpacing="0">
                <thead className="products__head">
                    <tr>
                    <th className="table--title">Product name</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Category</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price (including VAT)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                  {listsProducts}
                </table>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import `Link` from `react-router-dom` in products file:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
```

and replace this lines:

```
const listsProducts = this.state.productsData.map(listProduct => {
        return <tbody className="products__body">
                <tr>
                    <td><Link to={"/products-details/"+listProduct.id}>{listProduct.title}</Link></td>
                    <td>{listProduct.category}</td>
                    <td>{listProduct.price}</td>
                    <td>{Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100}</td>
                </tr> 
          </tbody>
      })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! And then to display the data I have to retrieve the data in the 'productsDetails' page and it will work for all the links or do I have to create a new page for each product?

Comment: create one 'productsDetails' page. you can get the `id` from the path by write `const id = props.match.params.id` in the head of the productsDetails component